# Decrement a for loop onto a vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

My instructor wants us to decrement from 5 to -4 using a for loop, then push those numbers onto a vector.
I don't understand why it's not decrementing. 
The compiler says `std::out_of_range`

The for loop obviously works without the vector involved, however I don't understand why it doesn't with it...?

```
int main() {

vector<int> number;

for (int i = 5; i >= -4; --i){

    number.push_back(i);
    cout << number.at(i) << endl;

}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `push_back` doesn't add an element AT that location. It adds an element with that value to the end of the `vector`. If you want a reference to the last element in a `vector` use `vector::back`. (`cout << number.back() << endl;`) Look at a reputable documentation source of the classes you're using. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is decrementing fine.  Your use of the vector's `at()` method is simply wrong.  You are getting the runtime error because the numbers you are pushing into the vector are not valid indexes into the vector, so you are indeed going out of bounds.  `at()` performs bounds checking, throwing a `std::out_of_range` exception if the requested index is `< 0` or `>= size()`.

Fill the vector first, THEN display its content, eg:

```cpp
int main() {

    vector<int> numbers;

    for (int num = 5; i >= -4; --i){
        numbers.push_back(num);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i){
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    /* or, in C++11 and later:
    for (int num : numbers){
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating two things here: 
The first is the value(s) that you've put into the vector. 
The second is the position of the items in the vector.

If you remove the line `cout << number.at(i) << endl;`, it should run w/o an error, and at the end of the loop, you will have a vector with 10 items in it: `5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4`.

But when you say `at(i)`, you're asking for an item at a particular position in the vector. If that position is outside of the range `[0.. size of vector)`, then `at` will throw an exception.

(Later) If what you want is to print the element that you just added, then `v.back()` will give you the last element in the vector.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes much more sense now. Appreciate the help